# How can I format cents only when needed in Oracle SQL server

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I format a column in Oracle SQL such that when the number has no cents in it it does not show however when it has cents then it would show it.

i.e.

```
113.00 would show as 113

113.11 would show as 113.11

113.10 would show as 113.10
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sometimes the best solution is to ask "why".  Personally, it would drive me nuts if I had to read a report where a listing of numeric values that did not use a consistent number of decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `case` and convert to a string:

```
select (case when col = trunc(col) then to_char(trunc(col))
             else to_char(col, 'FM999.00')
        end)
```